# Read elements with given indices from an array with arbitrary number of axis

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'd like to write a routine, which reads out the values of certain elements from an array. The element selection is specified as an array, where each row contains the indices for one element. The routine should work for arrays with arbitrary number of axes.

I could come up with the solution below, but I do not like it, as the conversion to tuple (or list) feels somehow unnecessary, although I need that to prevent advanced indexing. Is there any more numpythonic way to do this?

```
import numpy as np

def get_elements(aa, inds):
    myinds = tuple(inds.transpose())
    return aa[myinds]

AA = np.arange(6)
AA.shape = ( 3, 2 )
inds = np.array([[ 0, 0 ], [ 2, 1 ]])
data2 = get_elements(AA, inds)   # contains [ AA[0,0], A[2,1] ]

BB = np.arange(12)
BB.shape = ( 2, 3, 2 )
inds = np.array([[ 0, 0, 0], [ 1, 2, 1 ]])
data3 = get_elements(BB, inds)  # contains [ BB[0,0,0], BB[1,2,1] ]
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the tuple conversion actually isn't too inefficient here. It creates a tuple of views of `inds`, so there's no copies made (just new python objects that reference the same memory).  There's another way to do this, but it's much more round-about (combine `np.take` and `np.ravel_multi_index`, e.g. `b.take(np.ravel_multi_index(inds.T, b.shape))`).

Comment: Many of the `numpy` functions do just that - take index or axis numbers, and generate a tuple index from that.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks. Indeed the ravel_multi_index() function would be also an option I did not think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tuple(ind.T)` produces the same thing as `np.where` for the same elements.

```
In [117]: AA=np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
In [118]: ind=np.array([[0,0],[2,1]])
In [119]: tuple(ind.T)
Out[119]: (array([0, 2]), array([0, 1]))
In [120]: AA[tuple(ind.T)]
Out[120]: array([0, 5])
```

Using `where` to find the indices of these 2 values:

```
In [121]: np.where((AA==0) + (AA==5))
Out[121]: (array([0, 2]), array([0, 1]))
```

And copying from the doc for `where`, another way of finding the `[0,5]` values:

```
In [125]: np.in1d(AA.ravel(), [0,5]).reshape(AA.shape)
Out[125]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [126]: np.where(np.in1d(AA.ravel(), [0,5]).reshape(AA.shape))
Out[126]: (array([0, 2]), array([0, 1]))
```

So your `tuple` is perfectly good `numpy` code.

From `numpy` indexing documentation:

> Note
>   In Python, x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)] is equivalent to x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.

Comment: +1 only a remark that the syntactic sugar part is valid for fancy indexing with NumPy arrays...